# ROS Webcam Stream Really Slow

Tags: ros, computer-vision, raspberry-pi, cameras, monocular

I am trying to stream the images from my camera to a VM via ROS. Here is my setup:

- Raspberry Pi 3B+ with Picamera v2. It is running ROS Noetic with `cv_camera_node`
- An Ubuntu 20.04.1 VM with ROS Noetic. I am reviewing the live stream using `rosrun rqt_image_view rqt_image_view`

When I tried this, the stream is really laggy and slow. I am barely getting 10 fps. I was able to do camera calibration with it but mapping with it will be really challenging. Is there any way to speed it up. Can I decrease the quality of the camera capture? Any help is truly appreciated.

Here is my launch file:

````
<launch>
  <node name="usb_cam" pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node" output="screen" >
    <param name="video_device" value="/dev/video0" />
    <param name="image_width" value="640" />
    <param name="image_height" value="480" />
    <param name="pixel_format" value="uyvy" />
    <param name="camera_frame_id" value="camera" />
    <param name="io_method" value="mmap"/>
    <param name="framerate" value="30" />
    <param name="autofocus" value="true" />
    <param name="camera_name" value="camera" />
    
  </node>
  <node name="image_view" pkg="image_view" type="image_view" respawn="false" output="screen">
    <remap from="image" to="/camera/image_raw"/>
    <param name="autosize" value="true" />
  </node>
</launch>
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using VMWare. For some reason, when I used a physical machine with ROS and Ubuntu, it worked! Maybe there is a fix in VMWare. If anybody knows the solution, they are free to explain.

Answer (score 0):

What camera are you using? It might be helpful to know since the driver might be at fault here.
Also, any particular reason you are working with the cv_camera_node? [usb_cam](http://wiki.ros.org/usb_cam) has worked much better for me in the past. It works with libusb rather than opencv which could also be a culprit here. In the end, you just get a sensor_msgs::Image with both packages. So it'd be worth a shot. You can also set a bunch of different parameters in the launch file itself. Maybe play around with those? Specifically the framerate and image width/height.

Comment: I am using the following camera:
https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.vfU-KaUlgYFKNN_kF3qHuQHaFm?w=274&h=207&c=7&o=5&pid=1.7

Comment: I can try that!

Comment: I tried the usb_cam package but it is still the same.

Comment: What's your image size/resolution?

Comment: My camera is 2K(16:9) at 30fps. I set it to 640x480 at 30fps. The pixel format is yuyv. I will attach the entire launch file above.

Comment: But I also get the following error:


ERROR: cannot launch node of type [image_view/image_view]: image_view
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/noetic/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/pi/catkin_ws/src
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/noetic/share

Comment: Are you sure you have the image_view package installed? try `apt install ros-noetic-image-view` and source your ros path again.

Comment: I tried that and it says that the package cannot be found.

Comment: I was able to install it by manually downloading the package and then completing the kdl dependency. I get no errors now but the video is still laggy.

Comment: This might be a limitation of the rpi itself. Maybe with the ROS overhead, it might not be able to stream at 30fps. Do you have access to a PC? can you try the same with ROS on a PC/laptop to make sure the camera itself isn't acting funny?

Comment: I am using the camera with the camera ribbon and I don't have a spare USB camera.

Comment: I have a laptop with a webcam, however.

Comment: Yeah the webcam won't help unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Raspberry Pi camera and not a USB camera, it is better to use this node: https://github.com/UbiquityRobotics/raspicam_node. This gave me really good speed.